# Why does [a-zA-Z] match both numbers and letters?

Tags: php, regex

I want a variable that allow `letters and only`, not `digits`.

**And that variable can be at any position in the string.**

Look at this,

```
$pattern = '~user/(:var)~';

$pattern = str_replace('(:var)', '([a-zA-Z])', $pattern);

// Note, the variable contain both numbers and letters
$test = 'user/dave123';

$r = preg_match($pattern, $test); 

var_dump($r); //1 Success (I don't want this)
```

All I want is,

If a variable contain letters only, then `preg_match()` should return `1`,
but if that one contains at least one digit, then `preg_match()` should immediately return 0,

What `regex` should be defined instead of `([a-zA-Z])` and why `([a-zA-Z])` matches both numbers and letters!?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the regex? Have you dumped the `$pattern` to see that the regex being generated is as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regular expression is matching this substring of your test value: `user/d`.

If you want to check against the whole string, add start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to your pattern:

```
$pattern = '~^user/(:var)$~';
```

To check against the start/end of a string **OR** another delimiter such as `/`, it would look like this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:^|/)user/(:var)(?:$|/)~';
```

This will force it to consider the entire value up until either the end of the string or the next `/`... preventing partial matches like you encountered in your question.

(The `?:` indicates a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group), which means that the extra `()` groups won't end up in your resulting list of matches)

You'll also need to allow the `[a-zA-Z]` class to repeat with `+`, or it will only match single-character usernames:

```
$pattern = str_replace('(:var)', '([a-zA-Z]+)', $pattern);
```

Comment: Well, `(:var)` can be at any position, not only in the in the end, therefore I cannot rely on `$`

Comment: `/post/(:var)/comment/(:var)/replyid/(:var)`, how about this?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, it works as expected! I'm writing a router that accept both static and dynamic `URI` segments, so I'm still having troubles with `(:var)` in random position in the `URI` string. Couldn't please direct me in the right direction, what can be done about it?

Comment: @metal_fan, if this particular problem is solved, it's probably simpler to post a new question with an updated example incorporating what you learned in this question, and illustrating the problems you're still having.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give starting the ending using `^` and `$` respectively.

```
'~^user/(:var)$~'
```

It matches because, you have `user`, `dave` in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern means "one of any character between a-z or A-Z", which is why it matches. It doesn't offer a check to see if it is the *only* thing that matches, and it will not match repeated characters.

Instead of that approach, why not try something simpler. Since all you want to know is if the string contains a number or not:

```
$haystack = 'user/dave123';
foreach(range(0,9) as $i) {
    if (strpos($haystack,$i) === FALSE)) {
         return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

This will stop at the first number that is found.

Comment: One of any character between those ranges.

Comment: wait... `strpos()` either returns `INT` or `FALSE`, but it never returns `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the pattern is matching against the first character in the string and no against the whole string. To match against the whole string, try

`"/^[a-z]+$/i"`

which should give you a case insensitive letter only match on the whole string (`^` and `$` are *start of string* and *end of string*  delimiter characters).

There are also some handy inbuilt PHP functions like `ctype_alpha()` which do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Not possible, inevitable. ;)  I'm assuming the space between the `]` and `+` was a typo because the regex makes no sense with it there.  You left out the opening `/`, too.

Comment: BTW, the OP is now saying the match won't always occur at the end of the string, so the `$` won't do.